# How to send email using angular 9

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, nodemailer

The following code send email from server side. How to I use that code in Angular 9 application.
Could you please help some one for this.

```
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
    user: 'test@test.com',
    pass: 'xxxx'
    }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
    from: 'test@test.com',
    to: 'test@test.com',
    subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
    text: `Hi, thank you for your nice Node.js Email.`
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Well, you need to expose an API that when called sends the email.

Comment: You do not want to send email through Angular as Angular is a front-end framework which means it is fully exposed to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the above code will works i the Angular application, but the big problem doing that, is you will have exposed mail transport credentials in your front app. As mentioned before, best solution is create a simple API that send the email on server side.

Comment: Hum... But this API will be public, isn't it?